# The method Lambda(Expression body, params ParameterExpression[] parameters) in System.Linq.Expressions.Expression class become more and more slow

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a performance issue on a MVC application. I need to parse lambda expressions by the corresponding strings in run-time. When te application starts it works fast and well, but the execution time increases more and more each time i call the method. The CPU and RAM don't increase but the core method needs always more time.

When the application starts the execution time is just some millisecond. After calling it a lot of times the execution time become 10 ms, 100 ms, and so on. This is the snippet of code:

```
public static LambdaExpression ParseLambda(ParameterExpression[] parameters, Type resultType, string expression, params object[] values)
{
    ExpressionParser parser = new ExpressionParser(parameters, expression, values);
    var body = parser.Parse(resultType);
    var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(body, parameters); //this is the problematic call
    return lambdaExpression ;
}
```

The call to `Expression.Lambda(body, parameters)` is the one which takes always more time to complete.

After restarting the application the method become again fast.

To be efficient I should restart the application each hour or more frequently. But this is impossibile for a lot of reasons.

1. What is the reason of this loss of performance?
2. Can it be solved someway?
3. Is there a work around to regain the initial execution time without a restart?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is this `ExpressionParser`? Does it implement `IDisposable`?

Comment: Maybe the number of `parameters` and `values` increase over time?

Comment: ExpressionParser is in the namespace System.Linq.Dynamic, no it doesn't impement idisposable.

Comment: No, the parameters and values don't change in my simulation, i call the method with always the same parameters and the execution time magically increases

Comment: Create a test project with just lambda code and repeat same code multiple time and make sure that it is not the lambda code increasing the time.  It is probably something else in the code that is creating the issue.  It looks like the time is going up exponentially so it is probably a tree structure causing the issue.

Comment: *ExpressionParser is in the namespace System.Linq.Dynamic* -- But that's an internal class (??). Did you create a fork?

Comment: jdweng, thank you, but no, the problem is the one i highlighted, i am doing it in a test environment calling just that with always the same parameters, i try to pack a full test for you, but this is something we did already

Comment: it's and internal class, but it's open source, i used the source directly

Comment: To me this sounds a bit like there is some internal caching going on in the `ExpressionParser` class... Could you post the code of that class so somebody can take a look at it?

Comment: this is the class ExpressionParser, it is a .net. class: http://matematici.com/ExpressionParser.txt